# Error Correcting Tournaments (ect) Multi Class Classification in Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: classification, vowpalwabbit

I tried to go through [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.3176v4.pdf) which describes the ECT algorithm but could not make much out of it.

I know it is different from one-against-al (oaa) and even performs better than oaa.I wanted a simple explanation about how ect works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECT and Filter trees are useful (only) if you have a very big number of output labels (classes), let's say N=1000. With OAA (one-against-all), it would mean to do N binary classification tasks for each example (during both training and testing). With ECT you can make the prediction much faster: log(N). You can imagine Filter trees (which are the basis of ECT) as a decision tree where in each node you ask whether the example belongs to one set of labels or another set of labels (using all the features, unlike original decision trees).

In general, ECT is worse (in terms of loss or accuracy) than OAA (but in some cases it may be almost as good as OAA). With N=10 labels, you should try OAA first. With N>1000, OAA is too slow (and even the accuracy is low), you should try ECT (or `--log_multi` or `--csoaa_ldf` in VW, if you can preselect a smaller number of labels which are relevant for each example).

See http://cilvr.cs.nyu.edu/diglib/lsml/logarithmic.pdf

Comment: With OAA (one against all), you would only need to do N = 1000 binary classification tasks, since you for each class c train a single binary classifier to predict between c and not c. With OAO (one against one), you would need N^2 classifiers, since you for each pair of classes (c_1, c_2)  train a binary classifier to predict either c_1 or c_2.

Comment: Oops, how could I write that OAA needs N^2? (Probably I confused it with OAO, aka wap=weighted all pairs, which was deleted from VW some time ago.) I fixed that now. Thanks for noticing.